# How can i print the screenshot of a page to a bluetooth printer

Tags: ionic-framework, printing, bluetooth, screenshot

Am currently using srehanuddin Cordova-Plugin-Bluetooth-Printer. I first take the screenshot of the page, save its URI in base64 try to print that data bUT THE PRINTER(Jingpu Bluetooth printer) seems not to interprete the data, because it prints some stuff that cannot be read. How can i take the screen and then print it?

Here is my code,

```
 printScreenShot() {
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create();
alert.setTitle('Print');
alert.addInput({
  type: 'radio',
  label: 'Bluetooth',
  value: 'bt'
});
alert.addInput({
  type: 'radio',
  label: 'Other',
  value: 'other'
});

alert.addButton('Cancel');
alert.addButton({
  text: 'OK',
  handler: data => {
    console.log(data);
    if (data == 'bt') {
      this.printVisible = false;
      this.backVisible = false;
      this.screenshot.URI(80).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.URI);
        this.printBluetooth(res.URI);
      }, err => {
        this.printVisible = true;
        this.backVisible = true;
      });
    } else {
      this.backVisible = false;
      this.printVisible = false;
      this.screenshot.URI(80).then(res => {
        this.printOther(res.URI);
      }, err => {
        this.printVisible = true;
        this.backVisible = true;
      });
    }
  }
});
alert.present();
```

}

```
 printBluetooth(URI) {
BTPrinter.list(data => {
  console.log(data);
  if (data) {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create();
    alert.setTitle('Paired Devices');
    for (let device of data) {
      alert.addInput({
        type: 'radio',
        label: device,
        value: device
      });
    }


    alert.addButton('Cancel');
    alert.addButton({
      text: 'OK',
      handler: data => {
        this.printBt(URI, data);
      }
    });
    alert.present();
  } else {
    this.global.toast('Error occured', 'toast-error');
    this.backVisible = true;
    this.printVisible = true;
  }
})
```

}

```
printBt(URI, mac) {
console.log(mac);
let loader_send_1 = this.global.presentLoader('Sending ...');
loader_send_1.present();
BTPrinter.connect(function (mac) {
  console.log(mac);
  BTPrinter.print(function (data) {
    console.log("Success");
    console.log(data)
  }, function (err) {
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(err)
  }, URI)

}, function (err) {
  this.global.toast(err, 'toast-error');
  console.log(err)
}, mac);
```

}

```
<button (click)="printScreenShot()" ion-fab>
```